# When shoud I use "Defining" vs. "Configuring" vs. "Creating" in a technical context?

Tags: word-usage

I am writing a technical manual on how to use a software.
I have doubts about the different usage of the words *define*, *configure* and *create* when describing the steps that must be executed to use this program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends, but lets try to explain from my perspective. Define and Configure is something you are doing before the execution of the program. For example you can define the algorithm you want to use, or you can configure output location. There is subtle difference, from my perspective define is related with the knowledge aspect of the program. The configuration itself is more IT part of the story, e.g. storing location, passwords...etc.
Create is related with some data, you want to create something and enter it into application. Create a new account for example.